# Highlight attributedtext UITextView using NSRanges to an array value?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: Test]
I haven't had much luck in searching, but I am hoping to make
story text animate (change colour)in sync with an audio clip
but I am quite stuck as to how (I'm quite new at coding)

I'm really stuck as to how to find the correct range, which word gets coloured and how to update the string in sync to a .caf;
how to connect it all up and colour the correct ranges
Im guessing I will run an action with duration (using the AudioIntervals array as timing)

```
//    int wordCount = 0;
int wordCount = 0;
int IndexCount = 0;
//for (NSString *word in wordsInArray)
    for (NSMutableAttributedString *word in wordsInArray)
  //*wordsInArray = componentsSeparatedBy whitespace
{

    if (wordCount < [audioIntervals count])
    //wordCount less than audioIntervals
    {
      NSString *Orange = @"Orange\n\n";//change text orange 
     // action with duration here on 
     //Original mutable string block/duration/delay AudioInterval

     //how does Range***********the bit i'm stuck on**********
     [attString addAttributes:Colour01 range:NSMakeRange(0,???)];
     [attString addAttributes:Colour02 range:NSMakeRange(???,???)];
     [attString addAttributes:Colour01 range:NSMakeRange(???,???)];
     //*************************************************************
     MyText.attributedText = attString;
```

**I'm confused how the range works - how I can use the interval times with range? so the correct word is picked to be coloured or returned to the original colour)**
        }

```
    ...more code

    wordCount++;
    NSLog(@"Time  %@, %i, Index %@\n\n",word,wordCount,[audioIntervals objectAtIndex:IndexCount]);
    IndexCount++;
    rangeStart = rangeEnd +1;
```

}
}

**LOG shows AudioInterval duration, time to text colour, the colour + the word count but how do I Get the right range on the UITextField?? on this I am stuck!**

```
//which shows the plists and word count 
//and colourswap logic are working

Duration 0.176387 @Colour to Orange
Time 0.176387 @Colour to Black
this, 1,
Duration 0.274997 @Colour to Orange
Time 0.274997 @Colour to Black
is, 2,
Duration 0.345829 @Colour to Orange
Time 0.345829 @Colour to Black
the, 3,
Duration 0.612493 @Colour to Orange
Time 0.612493 @Colour to Black
text, 4,
Duration 0.9763770000000001 @Colour to Or
Time 0.9763770000000001 @Colour to Black
for, 5,
```

//In simple tests I can colour a few words in a sentence
but how can I use it to update the coloured word to sound timing see
"boldTextinRangeWithColour" test,

```
//my small test of applying a style to text in a UITextView
//its result is the photo you see
```

-(void)boldTextinRangeWithColour 
        {
            NSString *infoString =content;

```
    //NSMutableAttributedString alows bold styling
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString=
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:infoString];

    //styling
    UIFont *font_regular=
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:30.0f];
    UIFont *font_bold=
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:30.0f];
    UIColor* textColorBlack = 
    [UIColor blackColor];
    UIColor* textColorRed = 
    [UIColor redColor];

    NSDictionary *Colour01 
    = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColorBlack,
    NSFontAttributeName : font_regular,
    };

    NSDictionary *Colour02 
    = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColorRed,
    NSFontAttributeName : font_regular,
    };

    /*attString is a NSMutableAttributedString 
    a paragraph of story text*/

    [attString addAttributes:Colour01 
    range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)]; //Black
    //how do ranges work can I use AudioIntervals or wordcount
    //to find the correct word to colour

    [attString addAttributes:Colour02 
    range:NSMakeRange(5, 15)]; //Orange

    [attString addAttributes:Colour01 
    range:NSMakeRange(16, infoString.length - 15 - 1)];//Black

    MyText.attributedText = attString;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the "NSarray of timing durations Range" that you named in the title of your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`AVAudioPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/) to play your sounds, you can use the [`AVAudioPlayerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008068) method, `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` to know when the sound has stopped playing, and move to the next word.

This is much more robust than relying on timing, and if your audio or changes, you don't need to update any timing data.

**EDIT**

Before you play the story, you could use [enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:) to find the range of each word and store it in an array. You could use the option `NSStringEnumerationByWords` to enumerate by each word. The block will then give you the range for each word it finds and you can store that in the array.

When the story plays, after each `NSTimer` expiration (created from your array of word timings), you would highlight the next word.

You could also use [`dispatch_after()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after) instead of `NSTimer`.

Comment: The timing is quite accurate (since its running off audacity timing markers, which is very simple to set up) 

The program needs to understand when each word is played on the Mp3, and sync to the sounds as they are played (by changing text colour)

but how do you move to the next word (that I would like to know!)
how do you identify current word, previousword/s, nextword/s

How to find which word in the string to colour (the range)
How to find words before and after (the range) 
How, highlighted (range) to colour back after duration

Thanks

Comment: I think I follow now. So your audio is an entire story and you need to sync the words in the audio to moving your text highlighting. You could set an `NSTimer` for each time that the word will start. You could either set all of the timers ahead of time, or set the timer for the next word when the current timer expires. When the timer expires, highlight the next word.

Comment: Yes thats right, the audio is an entire story and I wish to sync the words
I have the timings stored as a list (inside a plist) - the **audioIntervals**

however I am confused how to find the correct word to highlight inside the array - the ranges How to find words before and after word to highlight

Comment: See my edit above for an idea of how to find the ranges for each word.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks yes I'm hoping I can use NSMutableAttributedString, and control the ranges - to find the correct word based off the word count (at least I hope this is possible?) It's the bit I'm stuck on...

Answer (score 0):

managed to get it working by starting rangeStart, rangeEnd 
this value increments starting at 0 - the starting point of the
sentence, where the first word begins I then calculated the length of the word, and made that the end range, each time in increments I add to the values - **rangeStart, rangeEnd are the values I needed to colour the correct word in the paragraph**
hope it helps someone else!

```
    SKAction *Delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:[[audioIntervals objectAtIndex:wordCount] floatValue]];
    SKAction *completion = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [attributedString addAttributes:orange range:NSMakeRange(rangeStart, rangeEnd)];
        MyText.attributedText = attributedString;
        NSLog(@"rangeStart %d rangeEnd %d",rangeStart, rangeEnd);
    }];
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[Delay,completion]];
    [self runAction:sequence];
```